# Rabbitmq, Redis and Hazlecast in a scalable microservice architecture

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, microservices, scalability, hazelcast

I have a question concerning the scalability within a microservice architecture:

> Independent from the inter service communication style (**REST HTTP** or
>   **messsage based**), if a service scales, which means several replicas of
>   the service are going to be launched, **how is a shared main memory
>   realized?** To be more precise, **how can instance1 access the memory of
>   instance2?**

I am asking this question because a shared non in-memory database between all instances of a service can be way to slow in read and write processes.

> Could some expert in designing scalable system architecture explain,
>   **what exactly is the difference** in using the (open source) **Redis**
>   solution or using the (open source) **Hazlecast** solution to this
>   problem?

And as another possible solution: Designing scalable systems with **Rabbitmq**:

> Is it **feasible to use message queues as a shared memory solution**, by
>   sending large/medium size objects within messages to a worker queue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Message queues generally don't handle large objects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47544515/1472222) for details. The rest of your question is at best too broad. Can you narrow it down, or ask a more specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> several instances of the service are going to be launched, how is a shared main memory realized? To be more precise, how can instance1 access the memory of instance2?

You don't. **Stateless** workload scales by adding more replicas. It is important that those replicas are in fact *stateless* and *loosely coupled* - shared nothing. All replicas can still communicate with an in-memory service, or database, but that stateful service is it's own independent service (in a microservice architecture).

> what exactly is the difference in using the (open source) Redis solution or using the (open source) Hazelcast solution to this problem?

Both is a valid solution. Which is best for you depends on what libraries, protocols, or integration patterns is best for you.

> Is it feasible to use message queues as a shared memory solution, by sending large/medium size objects within messages to a worker queue?

Yes, that is perfectly fine. Alternatively you can use a distributed pub-sub messaging platform like [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) or [Apache Pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/)

Comment: sry, it seems that i mixed the terminology here: with instance i meant replica here. Not sure what else can be meant by instance. I don't meant a physical instance.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I probably give a direct use case example to give a better basis to discuss. One main question is, can database access be a huge bottleneck and can one overcome this bottleneck by using a memory solution and when yes, which is an appropriate one to the actual problem?

Comment: @Jwf instances and replicas is the same thing in my answer, sorry for not using the same word as you did.

Comment: @Jwf databases can be a bottleneck, but that is a different question. You can scale databases or add caches... it all depends on your situation.

Comment: thanks for your input. I posted a more specific use case to this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902946/microservices-architecture-for-highly-frequent-data-access-in-memory-solutions

Comment: like to here your input on this @Jonas